# Get the absolute position of a ref element inside a scrolling div?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react element to which I assign a ref, and when clicking I would like to get the position of the element (just the y). That code works:

```
<InnerElement
  ref={myRef}
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(myRef.current?.offsetTop);
  }}
/>
```

But it doesn't take into account if the element is inside of a div that is scrolled. If that parent div is scrolling, the value of `myRef.current?.offsetTop` will remain the same

Is there a way to get the absolute position of that ref in the viewport?

Comment: I'm looking for the position of the element, not the scrolling div, I'll change the code a bit if MyContainer is confusing

Comment: Get the `scrollTop` of the container, and do the math.

Comment: Can you use the MouseEvent's clientY? Or do you need the element's Y relative to the viewport?

Comment: @AndrewParks is it possible to get the element's Y relative to the viewport?

Comment: @CBroe I tried that approach, but it's a scrolling div and within it an accordion which is also scrollable so it makes it quite complex, I was hoping to get the Y relative to the viewport

Answer (score 1):

Use getBoundingClientRect() in combination with the window's scroll position:

```js
getBoundingClientRect().y + window.scrollY
```

Answer (score 0):

getboundingclientrect() Does it solve your problem!